# GEKKO error in model expression with array of variables and intermediates

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gekko

I am trying to use GEKKO for fitting and function parameters estimation.

I need to use arrays of variables and arrays of intermediate-type variables because of changing number of parameters to fit.
And got an error I think in a model.

```
apm some_ip_here_gk_model14 <br><pre> ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.1
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            0
   Constants    :            2
   Variables    :           15
   Intermediates:           22
   Connections  :            0
   Equations    :           24
   Residuals    :            2
 
 @error: Model Expression
 *** Error in syntax of function string: Invalid element: none
 
Position: 1                   
 none
 ?
```

how to check what is this error?
I am running this code in jupyter notebook and I tried to look apm file - didn't find it in the folder where this jupyter notebook is situated. Where should I search?

Here is the code.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import math

M = 10; m = 1; gj =1; n = 1
num_pulses_in_window = 4
сonstant = 1; ac = 1
el_init_guess = [1,2,3,4]
borders_left = [1,2,3,4]
borders_right = [1,2,3,4]
A1_c = (M/(M+m))*сonstant
gj_c = gj

# using GEKKO for preliminary estomation
xData = np.array([1,2,3,4])
yData = np.array([2.5,1.2,3.2,1.1])

model = GEKKO()

# parameters
x = model.Param(value = xData) 
z = model.Param(value = yData) 

# constants
A1 =  model.Const(A1_c)
gj = model.Const(gj_c)

# variables
E = model.Array(model.Var, num_pulses_in_window)
G1 = model.Array(model.Var, num_pulses_in_window)
G2 = model.Array(model.Var, num_pulses_in_window)
Gg = model.Array(model.Var, num_pulses_in_window)

#Intermediates
k_alfa = model.Intermediate(A1*model.sqrt(x))
ro = model.Intermediate(k_alfa*ac)
phi = model.Intermediate(ro)

G = model.Array(model.Intermediate, num_pulses_in_window, equation=None)
d = model.Array(model.Intermediate, num_pulses_in_window, equation=None)
f = model.Array(model.Intermediate, num_pulses_in_window, equation=None)

for i in range(0, num_pulses_in_window):
    E[i].value = el_init_guess[i]
    E[i].lower = borders_left[i]
    E[i].upper = borders_right[i]
    
    #G1
    G1[i].lower = 0.0000001
    G1[i].upper = 1
    #G2
    G2[i].lower = 0
    G2[i].upper = 0
    #Gg
    Gg[i].lower = 0.0000001
    Gg[i].upper = 1

    G[i] = model.Intermediate(G1[i]+G2[i]+Gg[i])
    d[i] = model.Intermediate((E[i]-x)**2+(G[i]/2)**2)
    f[i] = model.Intermediate((1-(1-(G[i]*G1[i]/(2*d[i])))*model.cos(2*phi)-((E[i]-x)*G[i]/d[i])*model.sin(2*phi)))

sigma_sum = model.Intermediate(2*math.pi*gj/k_alfa * (model.sum(f)))

y = model.Var()

model.Equation(y == model.exp(-n*sigma_sum))

model.Minimize(((y-z))**2)

model.options.IMODE = 2
model.options.SOLVER = 3

model.options.MAX_ITER = 1000

model.solve(disp=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Intermediates are not defined with `m.Array()` because they are defined with the `m.Intermediate()` method. Try using an empty list instead:

```py
G = [None]*num_pulses_in_window
d = [None]*num_pulses_in_window
f = [None]*num_pulses_in_window
```

For troubleshooting, open the run folder with `model.open_folder()` and inspect `gk_model0.apm` with a text editor. This is a plain text version of the model. The 4th and onward intermediates are not defined correctly.

```py
Model
Constants
    i0 = 0.9090909090909091
    i1 = 1
End Constants
Parameters
    p1
    p2
End Parameters
Variables
    v1 = 1, <= 1, >= 1
    v2 = 2, <= 2, >= 2
    v3 = 3, <= 3, >= 3
    v4 = 4, <= 4, >= 4
    ...
    v13 = 0, <= 1, >= 1e-07
    v14 = 0, <= 1, >= 1e-07
    v15 = 0, <= 1, >= 1e-07
    v16 = 0, <= 1, >= 1e-07
    v17 = 0
End Variables
Intermediates
    i2=((i0)*(sqrt(p1)))
    i3=((i2)*(1))
    i4=i3
    i5=None
    i6=None
    i7=None
    i8=None
    i9=None
    ...
```

Here is a script that runs successfully:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import math

M = 10; m = 1; gj =1; n = 1
num_pulses_in_window = 4
сonstant = 1; ac = 1
el_init_guess = [1,2,3,4]
borders_left = [1,2,3,4]
borders_right = [1,2,3,4]
A1_c = (M/(M+m))*сonstant
gj_c = gj

# using GEKKO for preliminary estomation
xData = np.array([1,2,3,4])
yData = np.array([2.5,1.2,3.2,1.1])

model = GEKKO()

# parameters
x = model.Param(value = xData) 
z = model.Param(value = yData) 

# constants
A1 =  model.Const(A1_c)
gj = model.Const(gj_c)

# variables
E = model.Array(model.Var, num_pulses_in_window)
G1 = model.Array(model.Var, num_pulses_in_window)
G2 = model.Array(model.Var, num_pulses_in_window)
Gg = model.Array(model.Var, num_pulses_in_window)

#Intermediates
k_alfa = model.Intermediate(A1*model.sqrt(x))
ro = model.Intermediate(k_alfa*ac)
phi = model.Intermediate(ro)

G = [None]*num_pulses_in_window
d = [None]*num_pulses_in_window
f = [None]*num_pulses_in_window

for i in range(0, num_pulses_in_window):
    E[i].value = el_init_guess[i]
    E[i].lower = borders_left[i]
    E[i].upper = borders_right[i]
    
    #G1
    G1[i].lower = 0.0000001
    G1[i].upper = 1
    #G2
    G2[i].lower = 0
    G2[i].upper = 0
    #Gg
    Gg[i].lower = 0.0000001
    Gg[i].upper = 1

    G[i] = model.Intermediate(G1[i]+G2[i]+Gg[i])
    d[i] = model.Intermediate((E[i]-x)**2+(G[i]/2)**2)
    f[i] = model.Intermediate((1-(1-(G[i]*G1[i]/(2*d[i])))*model.cos(2*phi)-((E[i]-x)*G[i]/d[i])*model.sin(2*phi)))

sigma_sum = model.Intermediate(2*math.pi*gj/k_alfa * (model.sum(f)))

y = model.Var()

model.Equation(y == model.exp(-n*sigma_sum))

model.Minimize(((y-z))**2)

model.options.IMODE = 2
model.options.SOLVER = 3

model.options.MAX_ITER = 1000

model.solve(disp=1)
```

Don't forget to include dummy values in your script so that it runs and produces the error. I edited the question to include sample values in your question:

```
M = 10; m = 1; gj =1; n = 1
num_pulses_in_window = 4
сonstant = 1; ac = 1
el_init_guess = [1,2,3,4]
borders_left = [1,2,3,4]
borders_right = [1,2,3,4]
A1_c = (M/(M+m))*сonstant
gj_c = gj

# using GEKKO for preliminary estomation
xData = np.array([1,2,3,4])
yData = np.array([2.5,1.2,3.2,1.1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The concept with G = [None]*num_pulses_in_window  really helped, it runs. 

But actually I can't open the folder with model - I think it's because I am running the code on windows subsystem for linux (WSL) - I am getting the error like the message below

Comment: ...
   1844         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
-> 1845     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1846 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xdg-open'

Comment: Try printing the run directory with `print(m.path)`. You may be able to navigate to the temporary run directory through a command window.